# How to redirect all requests to one controller

Tags: laravel

In my case I have a menu, where which page has url.The urls are made dynamically when user creates the page and I can't add it to the `web.php`, because I don't know what is it. How can I add a `Route`, that will redirect all requests to `HomeController@index` for example?
There I can manage every request and render the proper view.

Comment: You mean that you have different urls that starts by something for example **page** in `youdomain.com/page/anything`?

Comment: Nope. All can start different. `/url1`, `/url2`. Can't make it by group, if you are asking about this. Or at least, I don't know how to group it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
Route::get('/{slug}', 'HomeController@index');
```

If you're worried about It'll conflict with other routes, just put this one at the very bottom

Answer (score 2):

This would catch ALL `GET` routes no matter how many segments are in the URI:

```
Route::get('{any}', 'HomeController@index')
    ->where('any', '.*');
```